# Amazon MWS - Max Order Quantity

Tags: javascript, amazon-mws

How can i Get and Set the "Max Order Quantity" on a product listing?
In some categories this is under the Offer tab inside Seller central.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi4rU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Amazon Feed API. Documentation you can find here: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDq8Q.png)

`Title` - REQUIRED

`SKU` - REQUIRED

`StandardProductID` - NOT REQUIRED BUT RECOMMENDED

This XML construction use like `SubmitFeed(XML)` and it will change your MaxOrderQuantity value

For testing it you can use amazon scratchpad site.

For set or updating "Max Order Quantity" use FeedType - "_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_"